# PL/SQL Procedure error

Tags: oracle, plsql

[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJ7zx.png)  [Error(19,3): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored]
[Error(20,8): PLS-00403: expression 'TOTAL' cannot be used as an INTO-target of a SELECT/FETCH statement],
[Error(21,3): PL/SQL: ORA-00904: : invalid identifier].

i am trying to write a procedure that retrieves the number of copies of a specific book, but i am getting the following errors if someone can help me with this that will be great. hopefully the image will help!

```
create or replace PROCEDURE copies_of_books (
l_ISBN IN INT,
l_title IN VARCHAR2, 
l_summary IN VARCHAR2,
l_author IN VARCHAR2,
l_date_published IN DATE,
l_pagecount IN INT,
n_name in VARCHAR2 := 'Orcale PL/SQLProgramming',
total varchar
)
AS

BEGIN
IF n_name IS NULL
THEN
  RAISE VALUE_ERROR;
END IF;

SELECT count(*)
into total
from BOOKS
WHERE title = n_name;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(total);
end copies_of_books ;
```

Comment: try total OUT varchar

Answer (score 2):

Your procedure specification has `total varchar`. By default parameters as `IN`, meaning they are read-only, hence the error. You need to make it `OUT`:

```
total out number
```

You probably also want it to be `varchar2`, not `varchar`. Well, actually, no, you probably want it to be a number not a string.

If you were passing a value in and changing it then it would be declared as `IN OUT`, meaning it would be read/write, and the caller would have to supply an initial value. With `OUT` it is write-only. Either way the caller has to supply a variable rather than a literal value.

You can read more about [subprogram parameter modes](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/subprograms.htm#LNPLS659).

For this sort of thing a function might be more appropriate:

```
create or replace FUNCTION copies_of_books (
l_ISBN IN INT,
...
n_name in VARCHAR2 := 'Orcale PL/SQLProgramming'
)
return number
AS
  total number;
BEGIN
...
  return total;
END;
```

Having a default book name seems a bit odd too, particularly one that doesn't look like it is likely match anything.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set your `total` parameter as `IN OUT`, so that you can modify it inside your procedure; so try simply changing your procedure in :

```
...
total IN OUT varchar2
...
```

Comment: Why `IN OUT` and not just `OUT`?

Comment: Simply for `dbms_output`; probably the OP only put it for debugging, but I preferred to avoid further errors

Answer (score 0):

Your use of `INT` as an input type I don't think is what you meant in this case, that's more the domain of middle tier apps, stick with `NUMBER`.
Assigning a value to an input paramter at initiation uses `DEFAULT`.
You use of `VALUE_ERROR` is a big NO! This is a genuine system error and should be left as such, for your purposes I would suggest using an `EXCEPTION_INIT` pragma event to raise a custom error see [EXCEPTION_INIT Pragma](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/exceptioninit_pragma.htm#LNPLS01315)

Aside from that this code should now work

```
create or replace PROCEDURE copies_of_books (
l_ISBN IN NUMBER,
l_title IN VARCHAR2, 
l_summary IN VARCHAR2,
l_author IN VARCHAR2,
l_date_published IN DATE,
l_pagecount IN NUMBER,
n_name IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'Oracle PL/SQLProgramming'
)
AS
total number(6) := 0;
BEGIN
IF n_name IS NULL
THEN
  RAISE VALUE_ERROR;
END IF;

SELECT count(*)
into total
from BOOKS
WHERE title = n_name;

DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(total);
end copies_of_books ;
```

Comment: The OP states that *"i am trying to write a procedure that retrieves the number of copies of a specific book"*. Your edit removes the compile errors but completely misses the point of the procedure - to return the number of books.

Comment: @MT0 no it does just that

Comment: It outputs it to `DBMS_OUTPUT` but it does not return the value from the procedure. You need an `OUT` parameter for that.

Comment: @MT0 a function would be better suited for that then, OP needs to revise the requirment. As a side I wonder how many of these questions are from actual professionals or just students looking for an easy out?